# Remove element from object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

How can I remove an element using its position of an object? I for example want to remove the second one.

```
Object {duur: ".short", taal: ".nl", topic: ".algemeen-management"}
```

Comment: Properties are not ordered. You cannot reliably say which one is the "second" property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: object keys don't have a [guaranteed order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Object.keys()` will give you in the order of how it is defined. **Always it is better to remove based on the key name.** Because, in an object, the **keys are not exactly sorted** and they **don't have any order**.

```js
var obj = {
  duur: ".short",
  taal: ".nl",
  topic: ".algemeen-management"
};
console.log(obj);
var position = 2;
delete obj[Object.keys(obj)[position - 1]];
console.log(obj);
```

The best and **right way** to do is to remove by the key name:

```js
var obj = {
  duur: ".short",
  taal: ".nl",
  topic: ".algemeen-management"
};
console.log(obj);
var key = "taal";
delete obj[key];
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It seems you are contradicting yourself. First you say `Object.keys()` returns the properties in the order they are defined, then you say keys don't have any order ;) To back up the second third sentence: `Object.keys({foo: 42, 21: 'x'})` (returns `[21, 'foo']` in Chrome, not `['foo', 21]`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah right. But, defined order is different... Well, eeks. I don't know how to put it correctly.

Comment: I believe what @PraveenKumar is trying to say (and assuming the behavior is like Python) is that Object.keys() will return the keys in some order, but there's no way to know what that order will be (may or may not be the order objects were inserted), and you can't guarantee that the order won't change if you call it again later.

Answer (score 2):

like this :

```
var index = 1 ; // the position you want minus 1

var example = {duur: ".short", taal: ".nl", topic: ".algemeen-management"}

delete example[Object.keys(example)[index]];
```

Comment: You might want to point out that this doesn't work for arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the delete operator like this:

delete myObject.taal;

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can siply use : delete(object.taal).

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the OP's question.